# How to remove "encrypt contents to secure data"

Tags: visual-studio, publishing-site, file-security

My website had problems loading an image, css file and a javascript file downloaded as a package from "Superfish".

I found the problem to be the "encrypt contents to secure data" on each of the files.
Ok, so I right-click -> properties -> Advanced and unchecked the "encrypt contents to secure data" setting.

However, when I re-publish using Visual Studio 2010, the published files have the setting flagged again.  The source files do not have the flag set, only the published files.  All files are deleted prior to commencing the publish.

I have completely re-created each file by pasting the contents in to a new file, but still when they are copied across the flag is reset.

I have tried publishing to another folder, but alas the new file still get created with encrypted contents setting.

It seems as though Visual Studio still thinks that this setting should be flagged, or it is copying a cached version of the file from somewhere which hasn't had the setting removed.

How do I stop the setting from being re-flagged after each publish?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with a CSS file.  The file was somehow encrypted inside the project folder, so when deployed, it was carrying over that flag.  Fixing it in the project folder solved the issue.

Check your local source, make sure it's not encrypted there first.  I know you said they weren't, but check again.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same issue. The source files were initially encrypted in my images folder. I unencrypted them in the source folder, but even after deleting them in the destination folder, publishing reset the encrypted flag in the destination files. However, after doing a complete rebuild of my solution, the problem went away.